# Put named range verticle

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have a named range (Sheet1!B1:Z7), that I want to place on another sheet placed verticle. Now I do this manually through:

```
=UNIQUE({Categorie!B:B;Categorie!C:C;Categorie!D:D;Categorie!E:E;Categorie!F:F})
```

But I would like to use the named range

```
=UNIQUE({Categorieen})
```

But that does not work.

I want to stack all the columns verticle

Is this possible? I could not find examples using named ranges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=UNIQUE(FLATTEN(TRANSPOSE(Categorieen)))
```

Reference: [FLATTEN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10307761)

Comment: It kinda works, but this still places it verticle. I would rather stack the columns (move the second column below the first one) on top of each other. Or maybe I have to assign every column to a named range!?

Comment: Modified. Please check.